# Brake caliper wont go back on on the drivers side

Tags: g6, caliper

I'm putting new brakes on the back of a 2006 g6 I have done the passenger side but when I went to pit the driver side back together the caliper will not line up right. I can't get the bolts to go in the hole and I have put the piston all the way down. It is like it is hitting something and I can't find what it is that is doing it. Can someone please help me

Comment: It's hard to say what might be wrong without some photos. You can click Edit, then add photos by clicking the icon that looks like a picture of mountains.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.